# react-window-infinite-loader material-ui autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-window

I am trying to show an infinite scrolled list inside a material-ui Autocomplete dropdown list, using react-window-infinite-loader. When I scroll to the bottom of the list, I want to fetch the next page of items from the server. I created [a codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-river-knn3r) which combines the [material-ui Autocomplete example for a virtualized list](https://codesandbox.io/s/cumpr) with the [react-window-infinite-loader example](https://codesandbox.io/s/x70ly749rq). When I scroll to the bottom of the list, the next page of data is loaded, however something is causing the list to scroll back to the top. How can I keep the scroll position after new data is loaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I got this to work by using the useAutocomplete hook. I created a sandbox which shows the working code: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-0fbyb

There is only one problem, that I still cannot figure out. When pressing the down arrow key on the keyboard to select items in the list, you can select items beyond the visible "window" of items. There must be a way to get the list to scroll to the selected item. I am guessing this is because the autocomplete ref needs to be set on the FixedSizeList component, but how can I do this when the InfiniteLoader *also* needs to pass a ref to the FixedSizeList component?

Comment: why can't you make this work using the AutoComplete component?

Comment: Same here..Would be good to have the infinite scroll working within the AUTOCOMPLETE itself